# Asymptotics for a random set cover problem

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, asymptotics, combinatorial-optimization

Suppose you are given a positive integer $k$ and a probability distribution $f$ on the positive reals.  I am interested in the limiting behavior of the following process as $n\to\infty$:

1. Create an instance of the set cover problem, with $n$ sets and $n$ objects.
2. Place each object in $k$ sets, chosen uniformly at random.
3. Let the cost of each set be an independent sample from the distribution $f$.

Is there any existing work that characterizes what happens when $n$ becomes large?  My intuition says it should scale linearly, but should also involve the random variable obtained when one takes the minimum of $k$ samples of $f$.  It should also take into consideration those sets that have an unusually high degree, which I would expect to follow a Poisson distribution.